# QGIS Shortest Path Calculation (Layer to Layer)

Tags: qgis, shortest-path

Using QGIS, I have a task for which I need to combine 2 point layers (with x-y coordinates in it). I managed to combine the points but they are only straight and I want them to follow the street pattern.

I came across Shortest Path option but it only gives solutions for points to layer or vice versa. Is there any way to calculate the shortest path between layer to layer? This shortest path function would be super useful for me if that can provide me an option to connect two points in layers having same ID number.

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to using the graphical modeler, it can be achieved using an expression.

###### Project layers

[image]

###### The model

[image]

1. The line layer representing your network
2. The point layer representing your destination
3. The Shortest Path (Point to Layer) algorithm (settings below)
4. The output shortest path

###### Settings for the The Shortest Path (Point to Layer) algorithm

[image]

5. The expression

```
geometry(
    get_feature_by_id(
        layer:='start point',  -- the name of your point layer with start points
        feature_id:=1)         -- the feature id of your start point
)
```

The expression will probably need tweaking depending on your specific needs, but this should  get you going in the right direction.

###### Result

[image]